# Displaying a Validation Summary using Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have a login form, which initially used the following syntax:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

I modified it like so:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, new AjaxOptions(), new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

In my form I show a validation summary like so:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Whenever I switched my form over to Ajax, I am not seeing a validation summary any more. Is there a quick fix for this, or will I have to do more work (alter my controller code to return a partial view etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your Ajax.Options targetid is not set. Specify one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.updatetargetid(v=vs.118).aspx

`, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TheDiv"})`

Make sure to have: `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`